# Move Wordpress Post Meta Value to a New Table via MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to move data that is in the wp_postmeta field in my Wordpress install to a new table and use the meta_key as the column header.

For instance:
post_id=1, meta_key=caramel, meta_value=3

I want to map this to a new table where the columns are:
post_id, caramel, and the values are:
1, 3

I have 14 meta_key values that I want to be column headers. I want the meta_value to be the value for each of these columns.

Is possible via MySQL?

Comment: what would use case be for doing this? Since meta-key values are variable and there will be many of them it doesn't really seem practical

Comment: @charlietfl I'm creating an index table to do calculations. Each post_id has values for each flavor profile (caramel, creamy, etc). I'm going to take each of those flavor profiles and subtract them and get the absolute value to try and find the profiles that are most similar for each post_id.

I figure the easiest way to do that is to create another table and then I can map all the values and then do the calculation.